the Detailed Architecture of EfficientNetV2-B2
I'm currently studying different neural network architectures and I'm particularly interested in EfficientNetV2-B2. I understand that this model is an improved version of the original EfficientNet, incorporating Fused-MBConv layers and other enhancements. However, I’m looking for a detailed breakdown of its architecture.
Here’s what I know so far:
EfficientNetV2 models are designed for faster training and better performance.
They use a combination of Fused-MBConv and MBConv layers.
The architecture employs a more flexible compound scaling method.
Specifically, I’d like to understand:

The exact configuration of each stage, including the type of layers, number of blocks, number of filters, and strides.

How the Fused-MBConv layers differ from the standard MBConv layers.

Any diagrams or resources that provide a clear visual representation of the architecture.


